# Offline documentation for specific version of pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Often I need to work offline for my python projects. How can I download PyCharm documentation for offline use?

Answer (score 2):

There's an option in PyCharm: go "Settings/Tools/Python External Documentation";  **BUT** it seems thishas not been working with local files for a long time due to a  `PyCharm` bug.

You can start a local server and pretend it to be a **docs.python.org** site.

1. Get docs [archive](https://docs.python.org/3/archives/python-3.6.3-docs-html.zip)
2. Unpack archive to folder named exactly "3.6"
3. Edit your **hosts** file:

*C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts* or */etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1       docs.python.org
::1             docs.python.org
```

4. Reboot
5. Run server. Go to the dir *where* "3.6" folder is located and run:

`python -m http.server 80 --bind 127.0.0.1`

for linux use
`sudo python -m http.server 80 --bind 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Rebash, interestingly enough I did same thing. However, I think this question should remain open until the bug is fixed or Jetbrains solves this.

Answer (score 0):

**1st solution** - automatic.
The PyCharm plugin **"PyCharm Help"** allows you to automatically download web help for offline use: when help is invoked, pages are delivered via a built-in Web server.

This solution has drawbacks - for me, it downloaded help only for one version of Python, but not for newer versions which I use in parallel.
Also, in that version of Python help, the local search doesn't work.

**2nd solution** - better, very flexible, but manual.

1. Download [Python's HTML help](https://docs.python.org/3/download.html) and unpack it into the folder with the corresponding version name, e.g., for Windows to "C:\py_help_server\3.12".
   *Folder "py_help_server" will become root folder for our server, and "3.12" naming should correspond online help's URL format.*
2. Run cmd as admin and run such commands:

   ```
    cd C:\py_help_server\3.12
    python -m http.server 80 --bind 127.0.0.1
   ```
3. For Chrome/Brave, download the plugin "Requestly - Intercept, Modify & Mock HTTP Requests". In its settings, go to "HTTP Rules", then "My Rules", click "New Rule" with the type "Replace String".

And create a rule like this:
If the URL contains "https://docs.python.org/3.12/", replace "https://docs.python.org/" with "http://127.0.0.1/".

Now, all pages of Python help for the 3.12 version will be redirected to our local server, which we started in the step 2.

This works for me like a charm. I tried to edit the hosts file too, but that didn't work for me at all.

Also, this last method has an advantage over the "PyCharm Help" plugin - the local web help's search function works well!